# Layout issue, want button at the bottom to remain stationary and still be able to read from previous view

Tags: android, layout, scrollview, android-relativelayout

This kind of problem is difficult to search and best explained by images.
Here is my current image.
[image: Button at bottom but cannot read String4's value]

Button is at the bottom but I cannot read String4's value. I tried padding, layout_margin , changing layout_width and layout_height etc. but in vain. Can anyone help me here? Any kind of information is appreciated.

My layout is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ScrollView
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

        <LinearLayout
            xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/labelInfo"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/priceInfo"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/description"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/brand"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/goToUrl"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"


            android:text="@string/buy" />
    </RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Please note there is scrollbar since first TextView's value can be quite long.I know one solution is to use Listview, but I am keeping that as last resort.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

first make **footer.xml** as shown below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/footer_bar"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"

android:layout_gravity="bottom">

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/footer_bar_bg"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:minHeight="50dp"
     android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" android:layout_centerHorizontal="true">



<Button
    android:id="@+id/footer_my_account"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_gravity="right"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/sepview2"
    android:layout_weight="0.35"
    android:text="My Account"

    />

</LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

after this chnage ur layout as shown below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"

     >
<include layout="@layout/footer"   android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"   /> 
 <ScrollView

   android:layout_width="fill_parent"
   android:layout_height="fill_parent"
   android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
   android:layout_above="@+id/footer_bar_bg"
   android:layout_marginBottom="50dp"
 >
        <LinearLayout   
           android:layout_width="wrap_content"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:orientation="vertical" >

            <TextView
               android:id="@+id/labelInfo"
               android:layout_width="wrap_content"
               android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
               android:textColor="#fff"
               android:text="aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaabbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccc"
               />

            <TextView
               android:id="@+id/priceInfo"
               android:layout_width="fill_parent"
               android:textColor="#fff"
               android:text="aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaabbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccc"

               android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

            <TextView
               android:id="@+id/description"
               android:layout_width="fill_parent"
               android:textColor="#fff"
               android:text="aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaabbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccc"

               android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

            <TextView
               android:id="@+id/brand"
               android:layout_width="fill_parent"
               android:textColor="#fff"
               android:text="cccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaabbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccc"

               android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView> 

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Thanks , I think you are missing something in your answer (RelativeLayout 's definition perhaps). From your explanation, I added the id to Relative layout and changed the scroll bar, but now I do not see anything in the labels.

Comment: I think you meant this:   <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:id="@+id/layoutgoToUrl" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/goToUrl"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            
            
            android:text="@string/buy" />
    </RelativeLayout>

Comment: Thanks. Now I do not see anything in the labels!. My source file is at http://pastebin.com/iHrifcvv and layout file is at http://pastebin.com/QTkkLr2a. Could you please take a look? I really want to accept your answer and believe because of your help, I am very close . Cannot pin point the reason though. Thanks for helping me out.You just need these 2 files to run this project.

Comment: Awesome, I cannot thank you enough. Happily accepted your answer. I hope people help you the way you did to me. Just one last question (you do not have to answer it if you are busy but I would appreciate it. I do not want just the solution but the cause too) , why could I not see text earlier?

Comment: Also, why did you have to include linear layout for wrapping button?

Comment: if i use single layout than accroding to ur requirment it is become hard to get bcz to put button at bottom we set property bottom than scrollview also get down as button intead of we have set align parent top that y i have done like for common footer for view